# Download videos from Youku

Tags: gratis, video, download-manager

There is a Chinese platform like YouTube, called [Youku](http://www.youku.com/).

I was trying to find a way lately to download videos from this website. However, most of the videos don't load outside of China. The online tools I use for YouTube don't work except the [SaveVideo.me](http://www.savevideo.me/), which is terrible slow. A video of 10MB needs about 30min.

I need a desktop software where I can add the link of the video from Youku and it will download it in reasonable time.

Platform: Windows or Linux (I have dual boot).

Optional: Add a link of a Youku channel and download all the videos from the user.

Comment: Have a look at Firefox with [FlashGot](https://flashgot.net/) and (optionally) [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/).

Comment: Have you tried OffLiberty?  http://offliberty.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download videos from Youku using [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/). It's a Python program for downloading videos or music from many sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google Chrome extension [Unblock Youku](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unblock-youku/pdnfnkhpgegpcingjbfihlkjeighnddk?hl=en)
 to access Youku web services from outside mainland China.

Comment: I tried this addon, but it only works to watch the video only. How then can I use it to download it?

Answer (score 0):

I know software named StreamFab All-In-One(https://www.dvdfab.cn/downloader.htm), which works well on most streaming platforms, but I don't know if it works well in China's platform. Maybe you could have a try with its free trial version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)